# Agregar estado = 1 o 0 para no aplicar una eliminación de un dato de la base de datos y como declarar en laravel el tipo del estado

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla producto:
id_producto, producto ,  (estado campo a crear)

y deseo agregar estado para no eliminar directamente sino pasarlo a un estado no activo, deseo saber como declarar en laravel el tipo de dato estado para manejar por 0 o 1 y como aplico a mi controlador

Answer (score 0):

Laravel te ofrece un trait para softDeletes, de manera que los registros no se eliminan; si aun asi deseas usar 1 y 0, debes usar bool en el modelo

Migración

```
$table->boolean('status');
```

Modelo

```
class Product extends model 
{
    protected $casts = [
        'status' => 'boolean'
    ];
}
```

Controlador

```
$product = Product::where('status', true)->first();
//Cambio de status (Inversor)
$product->status = !$product->status;
$product->save();
```

Comment: Esta consulta `$product = Product::where('status', true)->first();` me parece se puede reducir aún mas así: `$product = Product::whereStatus(true)->first();`